# Cannot send data outside runnable thread

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading, http-post

I'm having some difficulties with my app. I created a class with functions to handle HTTP POST by starting a thread, the issue is that I cannot send data outside the thread!!! The class has a variable and I want to set value to that variable when the thread is running, please help.

Here is the code:

```
package com.mypackage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class HandleJSON {

    private String urlString = null;

    private int errorcode ;
    public int getErrorcode(){return errorcode;}

    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
    public HandleJSON(String url){
        //saving the URL
        this.urlString = url;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
        try {
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void fetchJSON(){

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.connect();

                    //receiving message from server
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

                    // JSON thing
                    try{
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);

                        //THIS IS THE ISSUE, I'm setting here the errorcode which should set the superclass variable "errorcode" so I can use "getErrorCode" to retrieve the code, but it seems like the thread does not respond after thread starts;
                        errorcode = obj.getInt("error_code");
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Catch error", e.toString());
                    }

                    readAndParseJSON(data);
                    stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
    static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

}
```

Comment: so where is the problem? 
plz elaborate which variable you want to access and what error are you getting

Comment: Please read the comment //THIS IS THE ISSUE, when I set errorcode I cannot use it, and when I use getErrorCode I get the instantiated value which is 0.

Comment: Consider using the Volley framework for transmitting network data. http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue solved, I used AsyncTask instead and passed the variables to onPostExecute(String) which done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In such case, an anonymous daemon thread is a little tricky.
You can define a concrete class extending Thread, define data structures in it and provide the interface to access your data structures. Such as here below.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
  private JSONObject obj;
  public void run() {
    // Your parsing code goes here
    // Such as obj = xxxxxx;
  }
  public JSONObject getData() {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

Of course, you should consider the concurrent risks when manipulating inner data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get data between a non-main thread and elsewhere. In which case you may want to create another class that has a `public static` variable. This is such that everyone permitted by the modifier in question (`private`, `protected`, `public`) can access the same content. Be careful as, if poorly managed, your code may function differently or not all on systems with execution speeds other than yours.

Comment: The problem is that when I send signup information to the server I get a message with error codes that can mean "Missing params", "available email" etc. The message I get inside the thread is kept there, I cannot retrieve it!!

Comment: I was right. As soon as it receives some, have your thread put the data into a public static variable, typically one of another class perhaps your entry class.